# tp_smapi on the Lenevo Thinkpad T440p (or just battery thresholding)

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad

I'm trying to get the tp_smapi module working on my Thinkpad T440p for battery thresholding with tlp. However, when I run `sudo tlp-stat -b` it returns `tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)`. I've tried forcing the thinkpad_ec and tp_smapi kernel modules to load in /etc/modprobe.d like recommended on the thinkwiki. I've also read that there are alternatives to tp_smapi and that is not compatible with 4th generation Intel processors. I'm about to purchase a new 9-cell battery and would like get battery thresholding working for more longevity. Does anyone know how to obtain working battery thresholding on the Thinkpad T440p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you just implement TLP's [installation instructions](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation) *completely* and install acpi-call:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi-call-dkms
```

You may also refer to the [FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#battery) for ThinkPad battery troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the problem, http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html maybe of help.
Essentially, the point is your model may not be supported fully. But, you may go ahead and purchase that 9 cell battery and use it without apprehensions of a reduced life, because tlp takes care of whatever is amiss.